# Do number of input parameters in a callback function matter?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm learning Java Script at the moment via a course on Udemy, and I stumbled something I found peculiar.
It is about "callback functions" and the implementation in the course uses anonymous functions.

For example

```
var button = document.querySelector("button"); 
button.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("hi"); } ); 
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { console.log(event); } );
```

In the second line, the callback function is an anonymous function with no input parameters. In the third line, the anonymous function has one input parameter: event.

I feel like we are assuming that the callback can handle 0 or 1 input parameters, but how can we know for certain? What if I define an anonymous function with 3 input parameters? Would it matter?

Both lines will work, so I'm really surprised in the flexibility of the callback function.

Comment: It's not an issue in JavaScript; stating too few parameters simply means you won't be able to access all the arguments from the function call; stating too many simply means some end up undefined (also, this is the case for all functions, not just callback ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a feature of callback parameters. It's how functions behave in general in javascript.

A function defined with one parameter can be called with either zero, one or more than one parameter in javascript without any syntax errors:

```
function testing (a) {
    console.log(a);
}

testing();                   // will log undefined
testing('hello');            // logs "hello"
testing('hello', 'world');   // logs "hello"
```

This means:

- A function with zero parameters may be called with any number of arguments
- A function with many parameters may be called with no arguments

DOM events will always call your function with one argument (except on older versions of IE which will call them with zero arguments):

```
your_callback(event);
```

As such, you are free to define your callback with an argument if you plan to use it or omit the argument if you want to ignore it.

Comment: Your code example should say testing(); testing('hello'); testing("hello",'world'); right? Minor detail.. but anyhow this really helps.
Thanks for the clarification. That's a nice feature to JavaScript.

Comment: @mauvecrow Oh, yes. Sorry about that

Comment: @mauvecrow If you're wondering how a function can access parameters not in its arguments list, each function automatically creates a variable named `arguments` that is an array-like object of all parameters passed to it. It's how javascript implement varargs. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments